# How to extract a part of a sentence or string in Python using regular expression and strip methods

Tags: python, regex

For eg: 
Art Direction: Eve Stewart; Set Decoration: Ev...
Art Direction: Luciana Arrighi; Set Decoration...
Art Direction: Rick Heinrichs; Set Decoration:

I want to extract the 2nd element in the above string, **"Eve Stewart"** and create a separate dataframe column as "Art Directors".

```
#Art Direction: Eve Stewart; Set Decoration: Ev...
import re
art=[ ]

for row in before_2000["art_directors"]:
    found = re.search("Art Direction:(.+); Set Decoration", row)
    art.append(found)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.  You've made a good start; now finish the example and description.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
import re    
import pandas as pd

string = "Art Direction: Eve Stewart; Set Decoration: Ev... Art 
Direction: Luciana Arrighi; Set Decoration... Art Direction: Rick 
Heinrichs;"

pattern = "Art Direction:(.*?);"

art_directors = re.findall(pattern, string)
art_directors = [x.strip() for x in art_directors]

df = pd.DataFrame({"Art Directors": art_directors})
```

First you define the string data, then you define the regex pattern you're searching for. Finally, re.findall(pattern, string) finds all matches for that pattern within the string data. art_directors is a list and you can then reformat it into a pandas dataframe. I stripped the whitespace surrounding the cell values as well.